# Running vagrant up and ssh from command prompt vs. running in git bash for Windows

Tags: vagrant-windows

I think Git has changed its folder structure recently and now git.exe lives in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and ssh.exe lives in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.

When running `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` from the Windows command prompt, is there any advantage to adding both of the above paths to the environment variable, or just add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and run `bash` at the command prompt which would put me in a bash session where I could run `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh`.

Thanks.

Comment: // , I have the same question. Can you rephrase this to match the StackOverflow guidelines? I may have an answer for you.